# UIWebView memory leaks. What is the magic to release unused resources?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiwebview

Although there are many discussions about the subject, I have not still found an answer.

The problem is, that after the UIWebView loads a page, it will never release all the used memory resources.

I have created an empty project. Just added the UIWebView. The memory used before loading a request (http://methodhome.com/cleanhappy) was 4.5MB, and after loading has completed - 70 ~ 90 MB.

After releasing the UIWebView, the used memory was still 55MB.

So it looks like there are about 50MB of leaked memory.

I have tried next methods:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];body.style.backgroundColor=(body.style.backgroundColor=='')?'white':'';"];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML='';"];
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.open();document.close();"];
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
[_webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[_webView stopLoading];
_webView.delegate = nil;
[_webView removeFromSuperview];
_webView = nil;

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

I have also tried setting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
```

and have played with cache settings of memory and disk.
Nothing helped.

How can it be possible? How are the popular browsers are working like Safari and Chrome with such a leaks. What is the trick to release those resources?

Comment: I struggled with this also, there is a great article about this, it helped for me: http://www.codercowboy.com/code-uiwebview-memory-leak-prevention/

Comment: @oren Don't you noticed, that I have already used all the "tricks" from this article?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just noticed it after I commented. For some reason I thought that there is this article more tricks.

Comment: By the way, are you using iOS7 or iOS8? in iOS8 you can use WKWebView which handles the memory much better

Comment: @oren I need to support iOS 7 as well.

Comment: would love an answer too, this seems absurd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can it be possible?

`UIWebView` is an old API, based on WebKitLegacy. It's not deprecated for 1 single reason - Apple had no replacement (until iOS 9).

> How are the popular browsers are working like Safari and Chrome with
>   such a leaks.

Safari is a browser, created by Apple itself. It can use any hacks and private APIs, restricted in AppStore. Actually, for now Safari behavior is very close to `WKWebView`'s one. But it never was similar to `UIWebView`.

Only recently Google Chrome was able to migrate to `WKWebView`. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=423444 for details. Before that, Google Chrome was facing the same problem.

> What is the trick to release those resources?

I've tried a lot of tricks, but none of them worked for me. Unfortunately, the only solution is migration to `WKWebView`, introduced in iOS 8. Moreover, `WKWebView` had a lot of bugs under iOS 8, so in most cases it's usable only starting from iOS 9.